# Gravity Model - How many country pairs

Tags: modeling, stata

I would like to analyse differences in prices between different countries using a Gravity Model type regression. My question is whether I should include only unique pairs or include two pairs for two countries (i.e. only Germany-France or Germany-France & France-Germany). Since one pair is a linear combination of the other, I am thinking that this would not add any further information.

Additionally, I am wondering how the order of the variables impacts the independent variables. E.g. if I want to include country dummies, the order of the pairs seems to matter.